# How make disabled effect in UIKit to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

How make disabled effect to input supposably after click?
In docs:
https://getuikit.com/docs/form

```
UIkit.formCustom(element, options);
```

i try

```
<input id="name" class="uk-input uk-form-width-medium" type="text" placeholder="disabled" value="disabled" disabled>
```

and js

```
$( "#name" ).click(function() {
    UIkit.formCustom('#name', 'enable');
});
```

But it not workin :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "#name" ).prop( "disabled", true );
```

its not UIkit but... i dont found answer